# for R to identify columns

Tags: r

i have a data with 9 col and 7335 rows, and am trying to make R identify the columns when i try this

```
     <-ncol(Mydata)
         > 9 
      <-nrow(mydata)
      <-7335
```

but when i want it to show me the names on each header with this

```
       <-names(ncol)
       > NULL
```

and the headers on each columns look like this 
           <-("date","company","open","close","volume","capitalization")

please any help on how to make R identify the columns and its headers. and when i read the data, i added 
          <-header=TRUE
and secondly how do i calculate weighted average of the data.

Comment: Try colnames(Mydata)

Comment: please@JoachimSchork i tried is code ndat=mydata[capitalisation!=NA,] want to calculate weightedaverage..how do i go about it. when i run it.. it gives me error saying object capitalisation not found, after i did the colnames(mydata).   please help. thanks